# IDA Processor Module: How to maintain register values if instruction doesn't modify them directly (ex. STATUS register, FLAGS, etc.)?

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin, idapro-sdk

I'm developing a processor module for a specific microcontroller. There are cases, when instruction modifies some register (lets call it STATUS) indirectly. By indirectly, I mean, that STATUS is not one of the operands for this instruction. As an example, let's take `rlc` instruction:

```
rlc A
```

It basically rotates A left with Carry (C). C is part of STATUS register (just one bit). I cannot modify anything within the `ev_ana_insn` callback as per IDA Pro documentation, so it looks like that:

```
def ev_ana_insn(self, insn):
    if b == 0x67:  # rlc
        insn.size = 1
        insn.itype = self.itype_rlc
        insn.Op1.type = ida_ua.o_reg
        insn.Op1.reg = self.ireg_A
```

That's fine. But in `ev_emu_insn` I don't understand how and where should I modify the `STATUS` register, since it is missing (and shouldn't be there in the first place) from `insn`.

I had a couple of thoughts, but they are not good enough in my opinion:

1. Use `auxprefs` in `insn` or `specvals` in `Op1` and save the information about needed changes to the `STATUS` register. But still, I need to make these changes and track them somewhere during the analysis and emulation stages.
2. Map the `STATUS` register to RAM segment and modify it there. Here as example of such an implementation: https://github.com/Treeki/TM155-tools/blob/master/ida-module/ht68fb560.py#L470, but I don't know if it's the correct approach.
3. Put another `Op2` in my `insn`, assign it to the `STATUS` register and modify it during the emulation stage. However, this approach breaks the whole disassembler, since it expects 2 operands, but really there is only 1. I can play around with that during the output stage, but I don't think that it is a correct approach and is more like a hack.

So, any input is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually need to do that? What negative effects are you experiencing by not modelling the changes to the `STATUS` register? This is common on other processors also, such as `adc` and `sbb` on x86, and I think the dependency and modifications to `eflags` are simply not modelled.

Comment: Actually, I do. Some instructions with completely the same opcode have different mode of operation on operands (byte or word) based on flag in STATUS register. So, by not tracking this flag I don't know which instruction to display.

Comment: Is it possible to track the value of the `STATUS` register statically? Suppose `A` is loaded with the result of calling a random number generator before invoking some instruction that modifies the `STATUS` register based upon the contents of `A`. How would you model the update to the `STATUS` register?

Comment: Result of A is irrelevant. The only thing that could modify the STATUS register is a set of specific instructions, independent of the operand(s) contents. Also, it is being initialized during the RESET event to the predefined value. Therefore, it could be statically tracked.

Comment: Suppose every possible instruction that could modify the `STATUS` register was in a `switch` statement, whose `switch` expression was the result of calling a randon number generator. How would you track the value of the `STATUS` register? (I realize this is probably not what's happening in your binary, but the questions are intended to be Socratic.)